# Adding keys with empty values and then adding values in a nested format in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to create and add elements to a dictionary in the following format,

```
{{"source1": { "destination11": ["datetime1", "datetime2", ....]}
            { "destination12": ["datetime3", "datetime4",....]}
            ........................................
}
{"source2": { "destination21": ["datetime5", "datetime6", ....]}
            { "destination22": ["datetime7", "datetime8",....]}
            .......................................
}
.........................................}
```

All the keys and values are variables which I am getting from other modules.
 I have created an empty dictionary
call_record=[{}]
To add the "source1", "source2" as keys I tried,

```
call_record.append({source1 :})
```

Now i can't add a value to this key yet because i will be adding it  in the next lines, so I need to create this key with empty value and then add values as I get them from the next modules. But, this line doesn't create a key with empty value.

Besides, to add "destination11", "destination12"ets, I tried,

```
call_record[i].append(destination11)
```

But, this doesn't add the destinations as the values of the source key.

I have to add the datetimes, after I have added the destinations. Then I have to dump this dictionary in a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.append` is used to add an element to an array.
The correct sintax to add an element to a dictionary is `your_dictionary[key] = value`

In your case you can pass the arguments to your dictionary as follow:

```
import json

call_record = {} # To create an empty dictionary
call_record["source1"] = {} # To append an empty dictionary to the key "source1"
call_record["source1"]["destination11"] = [] # An empty array as value for "destination11"
call_record["source1"]["destination11"].append("datetime1", "datetime2") # To append element datetime1 and datetime2 to destination11 array
call_record_json = json.dumps(call_record, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I would however suggest to have a look at the python documentation to clarify the **[data structure](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html)** in python.

You can also refer to **[JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)** section of the documentation for further examples about how to use it.

Comment: If the answer was correct and useful, could you vote it and choose it? :)